# How to use NumberFormatter in laravel - 6

Tags: api, laravel-6, numberformatter

How to use "NumberFormatter" in Laravel function?

My Code is ( I need to covert number to Word )
Eg: 999 is like "Nine hundred ninety-nine"

```
$digit = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT); 
echo $digit->format(1000);
```

It gives Error like:

```
"message": "Class 'Modules\\Receipts\\Http\\Controllers\\NumberFormatter' not found",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
service apache2 restart
```